# Setting a DBGrid column format in Delphi

Tags: delphi, format, currency, lazarus, dbgrid

I am using a DBGrid component in Delphi. I wonder how I can set the format of a column.  I have real values that I want to be displayed as currency in the grid.

Someone knows how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Format a DBGrid Column to Display Two Decimal Places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271822/how-to-format-a-dbgrid-column-to-display-two-decimal-places)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can set the `DisplayFormat` of the `Field`
2. You can handle `OnGetText` event. This approach allows to do more complex operations with the value.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't add the fields to field Editor list you can get the formating by code as :

```
TFloatField(MyQuery.fieldByName('MyField').DisplayFormat := '0.00';
```

if you don't want to show the zeros replace '0.00' with '#.##';

Answer (score 2):

The first port of call is the DisplayFormat of the data field in the database itself.

Comment: I've set the column type to decimal(20,2) in my old MySql 4.1 database. Trailing zeros are not shown in the DBGrid.  Is there something else to set?