# How to Format a DBGrid Column to Display Two Decimal Places?

Tags: delphi, formatting, lazarus, dbgrid, elevatedb

I would like to format specific cells to force two decimal places. The data is coming from an ElevateDB stored procedure and hooked into a TDataSource.

**EDIT: SQL Programming Note:**

I wasn't sure if this was just an ElevateDB issue or not. Before knowing about the **Fields Editor**, I attempted to format the data at the SQL level by using a CAST (NumericField as varchar(10)) statement inside the stored procedure. By doing so, it did not expose the **DisplayFormat** property inside the fields editor for this particular field.

When I removed the CAST() statement from the stored procedure, the **DisplayFormat** property showed up in the **Fields Editor**.

Comment: Only numeric fields expose a DisplayFormat property - there is no use for it in string fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can format the DBGrid columns by formatting the underlying fields. If not done, create static fields in your dataset and then set the DisplayFormat property of the field in question to `0.00` and you are done.

Comment: How do you create "Static Fields"? How do you set the DisplayFormat?

Comment: Use the [fields editor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fields_Editor) to create static (also called persistent) fields. Each field has a property DisplayName.

Comment: I "Right-Clicked" and found the "Fields Editor". However... there is no DisplayFormat. I am so frustrated with Delphi right now I could spit.

Comment: Once inside the fields editor, right-click and select 'Add All Fields', then click on the field you want, and in the object inspector you should see the displayformat property, and set to ###.00

Comment: Thanks for your patience... please read edit to OP.

Answer (score 9):

I use same method as Uwe answered, in code after opening the dataset just add this line of code to format certian column:

```
  TFloatField(MyDs.FieldByName('Cost')).DisplayFormat := '0.00';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can format the field using the `DrawDataCell` event.

```
procedure TFormMain.DBGridCompareDrawDataCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if Field.Name = 'FIELDNAME' then
    TFloatField(Field).DisplayFormat := '#,##0.00';
end;
```